# Salesforce.com instance based on Client Geography

Tags: instance

I have question on Salesforce.com Security issue based on Client location and respective production instance.

My client is US based and instance that i got is ap1. My query is, does it make a security violation problem as my client location is US and production instance is ap1(instead of na30).

Does US client have such security constraints.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1. We can access any instance from any location.
2. if you want to restrict access, it can be blocked based on IP addresses.